# How to set slider to control video in MATLAB GUI?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, video, uislider

I am trying to set a slider in MATLAB GUI to control video like move into some frames of the video. The 'obj' is the video file selected by the user. The following code was used to take the input video and show in an axes of the GUI.

```
    global b    
    filename = get(handles.edit3, 'String');
      if ~exist(filename, 'file')
        warndlg( 'Text in edit box is not the name of a file');
        return
      end
      try
        obj = VideoReader(filename);
      catch
        warndlg( 'File named in edit box does not appear to be a usable movie file');
        return
      end

    axes(handles.axes2)
    handles.pushbutton5=0;
    guidata(hObject,handles);
    while ~(handles.pushbutton5)
        if hasFrame(obj)
        vidFrame = readFrame(obj);
        obj;
        image(vidFrame, 'Parent', handles.axes2);
        set(axes, 'Visible', 'off');
        pause(1/obj.FrameRate)
        end
        handles = guidata(hObject);
    end
    clear obj
```

The slider will provide "b" value while the user control the slider.

```
function slider2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to slider2 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: get(hObject,'Value') returns position of slider
%        get(hObject,'Min') and get(hObject,'Max') to determine range of slider
global b
 b = get(handles.slider2,'Value');
```

Does anyone know how solve this problem so that the video can be controlled by the slider?

Comment: Could you please formulate your question clearer? What property of the video would you like to control by the value `b`? Should it be the frame index? The playback speed or video brightness?

Comment: I need to jump or move into several parts or frame of the video using the slider.

Comment: The drawing of your video frame has to take place in the `slider2_Callback` function. There you need to access your video file and read the frame with index `b`. To get access to your data place them in the your `guidata`structure. Variable `b` does not need to be global then. But why don't you use the `implay()` function of matlab? https://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/implay.html

Comment: Can we use implay for the GUI? I have provide axes in the GUI. Is it possible to put the implay window in the axes of GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you own the vision toolbox of matlab you can use this solution from matlab:

[Video Player in a custom GUI](https://de.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/video-display-in-a-custom-user-interface.html)